# How to use migrated dbcontext in EF 7 ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have migrated a web system from asp.net core RC1 to 1.0.0-final. I am using Entity framework Core.
There is a problem when using the DB (sqlserver 2012), in any method that uses the context. This is the error:

> An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A
>   DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnModelCreating in any way
>   that makes use of the model that is being created.

I am sure that the connection string is the correct one (in rc1 worked)
The exception is handled by some EF code, but all the entitys are null so they throw an error when using the context (did not handle this posible error)

This is the stack trace from the 'context.Model' error

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
```

This is my context class

```
public partial class gestionContext : DbContext
    {
    public gestionContext(DbContextOptions<gestionContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }



    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Aux_ExampleEntity>(entity =>
        {

            entity.Property(e => e.code)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(13)
                .HasColumnType("char");


        });


        //more fluent api here

  }
```

This is the context related piece of code from the startup class

```
services.AddDbContext<gestionContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer("noparametrizedconnectionstring"));
```

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: Please paste whole `OnModelCreating` - according to exception,the body of that method has a problem.

Comment: There are 2000 lines of fluent api in OnModelCreating(), should i use data annotations on all the model? This happens because i used database first to build the model

Comment: No, it is fine. But definitely there is bug somewhere in your 2000-lines code.

Comment: Did you get line no where error occur ?